# How to check if a table row has a class name without using hasClass()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check whether a table row (TR) has a class by name.  So far, I have the following:

```
var myClass = "myClass";

//only myClass if it doesn't exist already
if (!(rowGet.className == "myClass") || !(rowGet.className == "myClass anotherClass")) {
     if (rowGet) { // only add the class if TR exists
         rowGet.className = myClass;
     }
}
```

rowGet is a TR from a table.  When I tried hasClass(myClass), I get an error saying HTMLTableElement has no method hasClass.  Yes, I have jQuery referenced.

Comment: Try `$(rowGet).hasClass("myClass");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to wrap your element with jQuery:

```
$(rowGet).hasClass('myclass');
```

---

Actually, there's no need to first check whether it already has the class applied, just use `addClass`:

```
$(rowGet).addClass('myclass');
```

It won't even complain if the element doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(rowGet).hasClass("myClass");
```